# VS Info Message: "Package restore on project open is disabled. Change the npm package management settings in Project Properties ..."

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

VS 2019 throws this info message: "Package restore on project open is disabled. Change the npm package management settings in Project Properties to enable restore on project open."

[image]

But I can't find any specific checkbox or "npm properties tab" in project's properties for this. Could you give me some details on it?

Answer (score 76):

In Visual Studio 2019 (and 2022), you can find this global setting in:

<kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Projects and Solutions</kbd> > <kbd>Web Package Management</kbd> > <kbd>Package Restore</kbd>

We have not yet found this setting in Project Properties.

Comment: But I don't want Visual Studio 2019 to "Restore On Project Open". How to avoid this warning?

Comment: @ChrisTomg I couldn't find a way. Technically it's a message not a warning, but I get it you probably want a clean Error List window. It won't download modules that exist locally so it usually does nothing. I turned it on to avoid the message.

Comment: You might want to vote on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1243025/cannot-disable-package-restore-on-project-open-is.html

Comment: or go into options press 'Ctrl+E' and type 'Restore' is the search dialog at the top

Comment: I'm getting the reported message, but in the package restore options indicated the "Restore on project open" option is already set to true. "Restore on Save" is false. What gives?

Comment: @CaringDev, status says it is fixed but it is obviously not. Web Site with VS 16.9.2 shows message.

Comment: @ChrisTorng 'Restore' is not 'upgrade' or 'change versions' etc ... there should be no harm in allowing a restore upon projects opening up.  I leave it set to True (on Project Open) and have never had an issue.  Personally, I think this should be the default.

Comment: I was getting two of these info messages, then I changed the option mentioned to True, and now I get one.

Answer (score 4):

Just found it!!!
If it helps anyone in the future

[image: img]